# Moving elements from one column to other two at a time in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two columns. Left column with elements

```
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L....
```

Right column with elements

```
1R, 2R, 3R, 4R.....
```

What I want to do is, if width is less than 991px, take two elements at a time from right column and put them in left column using jQuery. The final order should be 
`1L, 2L, 1R, 2R, 3L, 4L, 3R, 4R .....` 
If width is greater than 991px I want to rearrange the elements in original configuration.

I don't know the number of elements in each column beforehand. Any of the columns might have more elements. I want to keep moving elements until the elements in right column are zero or left column is all filled up to end. After that I want to append remaining elements to left column. Like this : `1L, 2L, 1R, 2R ...7L, 8L, 7R, 8R, 9R, 10R, 11R, 12R...`

up to this point. I have following code:

```
 $('#right-col').children().slice(0,2).detach().insertAfter("#left-col .item:first");
```

It inserts only the first two elements from right column to left and leaves rest untouched. I tried to create a loop like this:

```
 while($('#right-col').children().length>0) {
   $('#right-col').children().slice(0,2).detach().insertAfter("#left-col .item:first");
 }
```

This however puts all the elements after the first one (which is expected). How can I put the elements two at a time together in the way I mentioned?

This is my HTML

```
<section class="col-md-8" id="left-col">
  <div class="item"> Blah blah blah </div>
  <div class="item"> Blah blah blah </div>
  <div class="item"> Blah blah blah </div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div class="item"> Blah blah blah </div>
</section>
<section class="col-md-4" id="right-col">
  <div class="item"> Blah blah blah </div>
  <div class="item"> Blah blah blah </div>
  <div class="item"> Blah blah blah </div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div class="item"> Blah blah blah </div>
</section>
```

Here is a JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pczbe0qv/

Comment: You should show your html, people are less likely to help if we have to imagine the html that is in play :) If you can make jsFiddle that would be even better

Comment: Wait, are you basically using some table to layout your page and you want to rearrange the layout for different size screens?....if so .... STOP now if you value your sanity. Tables are not for this. Use the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) methods instead

Comment: @DelightedD0D Alright I will create a JS fiddle. Please wait :D

Comment: No I am not using tables. I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: Same goes if you're using divs to do this really, bootstrap will do all of that repositioning for you much better than anything we could help you rig up

Comment: How can I use bootstrap for it?

Comment: Check out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering this functionality in Bootstrap is used to reorder columns, it may take a minute to wrap your head around the functionality, but you'll be much better served in the long run :), here is a decent run down on the feature: http://www.schmalz.io/2014/10/08/Column-Ordering-in-Bootstrap/

Comment: @DelightedD0D I have one issue. The bootstrap grid ordering will move the whole column as one unit. I want to move elements two at a time. From left column to right column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you'd be best served by changing your layout to leverage "Column Reordering" built into Bootstrap.

Take a look at [Column Ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) and [Column Ordering in Bootstrap](http://www.schmalz.io/2014/10/08/Column-Ordering-in-Bootstrap/)

Something like this as an example ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13913/)):

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="item col-xs-2 ">L1</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 ">L2</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 col-md-push-4">R1</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 col-md-push-4">R2</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 col-md-pull-4">L3</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 col-md-pull-4">L4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="item col-xs-2 ">L1</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 ">L2</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 col-md-push-4">R1</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 col-md-push-4">R2</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 col-md-pull-4">L3</div>
    <div class="item col-xs-2 col-md-pull-4">L4</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, to get the functionality you want, there are going to be some complex calculations involved that are going to be really easy to break.